# How to read field values from AggregateResult

Tags: aggregateresult, group-by

I need to use group by cube to display the count of added services for each group for each package. I get an error on line 18: method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type List. How do I correct for this?

```java
public class AddedServicesGrouping {

    public list<Inspection__c> inspections = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Added_Services_Group__c, Inspection_Package__c, Id
                                   FROM Inspection_Services__r)
                                   FROM Inspection__c
                                   WHERE Status__c = 'Completed' AND Month_Since_Launch__c > 0];

    public list<Inspection__c> getservices(){

        for(Inspection__c i: inspections){
            for(Inspection_Service__c addedservices : i.Inspection_Services__r){
                AggregateResult[] ar =
                    [SELECT Added_Services_Group__c AddedService, count_distinct(id) cnt, Inspection_Package__c Package,
                    GROUPING(Added_Services_Group__c), GROUPING(Inspection_Package__c) 
                    FROM Inspection_Service__c
                    GROUP BY CUBE (Added_Services_Group__c, Inspection_Package__c)];

                integer n = integer.valueof(ar.get('cnt'));
            }
        } 
        return inspections;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to call `get` from `AggregateResult`, not `List<AggregateResult>`.

Instead of `ar.get('cnt')`, you could for instance do `ar[0].get('cnt')`.

Answer (score 8):

`ar` is of type `AggregateResult[]` (also known as `List<AggregateResult>`). You are aliasing correctly, but you must call `get()` on a single `AggregateResult`.

Reference: [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).